# pyttsx3 is able to speak, but cannot write to a file

Tags: python, macos, apple-silicon, pyttsx3, pyttsx

I started to experiment with pyttsx3 and got a problem with it. When I use a simple 'say' command, everything works well but when I try to save the voice to a file, my script hangs and never comes back. Using Mac on Apple silicon, if it is relevant.

Not sure if I need to deliver example code, but here it is:

Works:

```
eng = pyttsx3.init()
eng.say('Hey')
eng.runAndWait()
```

Hangs in eternity:

```
eng = pyttsx3.init()
eng.save_to_file('Hey', 'hey.mp3')
eng.runAndWait()
```

I also at some point suspected if the file should be there for it to write in, and created an empty hey.mp3 for it by using touch, but still no luck.

Comment: What do you mean by "hangs in eternity"? Does the program just keep on running forever and not do anything? When I run this program, it works fine for me. Did you run only the example code that you have provided here, or did you run a full program that uses speech recognition?

Comment: By hangs in eternity, I mean that the last line that I provided does not complete at all and the program stops forever while interpreting that one. My original program was somewhat complex with respect to these lines, but the example lines here is behaving in the very same way. At the end, if I just make the program speak immediately it is fine but when I try to save the speech to a file, it is freezing for me. I would love to clear any ambiguities still standing.

Comment: It might be an internal thing, or just with `pyttsx3`. I recommend recording an audio clip using python (no speech recognition or anything), using some module other than `pyttsx3`. Then try saving that audio clip to a file, and see if that works. Might just be a problem with `pyttsx3` saving stuff to a file on your computer, and in that case, there are plenty of ways to get around it.